# Посоветуйте способ генерации скриптов для сборки java приложения

Tags: java, bat, сборка, sh

Всем привет!
Есть ли какой нибудь способ генерации batch/shell скриптов для сборки java приложения? (Например, build.sh который создает jarник и appname.sh в папке dist для запуска приложения)[image: Пример скрипта для сборки]
Вручную уже ппц как надоело, да и смотреть на это дело без слез нельзя.

Comment: `maven` Вам в помощь. Или `gradle`

Comment: Примеры, как это можно сделать с Gradle: https://github.com/LeonisX/space-trader и Maven (maven-assembly-plugin): https://github.com/LeonisX/rom-shingler/blob/master/gui/pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Месье знает толк в извращениях. Генерация Java сборки на shell скриптах дело конечно благородное (и не запрещенное), но увы крайне неблагодарное и морально устаревшее.

В наше время применяются другие более совершенные способы генерации Java сборок.

Сейчас наиболее православным признан [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) также считается вполне кошерным средством, а еще лет 10 назад все пищали от [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/).

Если посмотреть на проблему шире и включить в сборку не только генерацию самой сборки, но также и его развертывание то картина рыночных долей будет такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: осталось воткнуть в этот граф докер с кубером